# MongoDB - datetime type for mongosqld

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB that have a `Date` field :

```
date: 2021-02-17T18:40:01.000+00:00
```

I want to expose this collection to a BI tool thanks to MongoDB BI Connector, `mongosqld`. I used `mongodrdl` to create the data model.

`mongodrdl` converts MongoDB's `Date` type to MySQL's `timestamp` type. When i read the date column in a BI application, the time is only zeros :

```
17/02/2021 00:00:00
```

This is catastrophic because i need the time. I tried to edit the drdl generated by `mongodrdl` and put the `SqlType` to `datetime`. But when i restart `mongosqld` i get the following error :

```
unable to create column "date" from drdl: unsupported SQL type: "datetime" on column "date"
```

How can i preserve the time for this date field to be properly exposed to BI tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date: 2021-02-17T18:40:01.000+00:00
```

This is a stringified (iso8601) representation of a timestamp. If this is how your timestamps are *stored*, they are of the wrong type (string, not timestamp) and hence produce zeroed SQL timestamps.

To fix, store the timestamps as timestamps (BSON date type).